# PHP - Re-format number with commas

Tags: php

there are several topics with pretty similar questions, but in my specific case, I failed to find an answer.

I have a number, such as:

```
 4,063,500.00
```

I need it reformatted in

```
 4063500
```

Is there any inbuilt functionality in PHP or Laravel that allows doing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, didn't work, I've got several dilimiters. At least I failed to achieve the needed result by using number_format()

Comment: $number = '4,063,500.00';
$number = str_replace('.00', '', $number);
$number = str_replace(',', '', $number);
echo $number;

Comment: If you google for any combination of "php number format" you will have the appropriate function as the first result... no self effort, no research has been done -1

Comment: What is the expected output of `4,063,500.50`?

Comment: If you know for sure that the input string always uses comma to separate the 3-digit groups you can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to get rid of the commas then convert the string to a number using [`(int)`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) or [`(float)`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). Or you can even pass it as string to [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to format it using a different number of decimal digits

Comment: @Andreas The expected output is 4063500. No delimeters, no zeros

Comment: Ok so you always want to round down and decimals?

Comment: I'm surprised there is no regex answers here yet.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Subjective and wrong opinion.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I forgot to specify that regex is not a solution, its way too heavier. I reached a solution similar to the one Dustytrash has indicated above, but it's too wordy, and heavy

Comment: I was joking! But there is a regex answer now. Always someone posting a regex answer on the most basic questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original number is treated as a string because of the commas. So at minimum you need to remove them before calling `intval()` which will truncate off the decimal:

```
<?php
$num = '4,063,500.00';
echo intval(str_replace(',', '', $num));
```

[And the output is](https://ideone.com/r2Y8F6):

```
4063500
```

Comment: Thanks, but here I will get decimals removed, like "4,063,500 ". Then I will split it by comma, will join the array, etc. Its too much fuss, my question is if it is possible to do in a shorter way.

Comment: This will round the number, not sure that is what OP wants

Comment: Ok! I wasn't sure either

Comment: @SeanBright Thank you! This is the most ergonomic approach, concise and straightforward!

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expression to remove all extra characters except number.
ex removing extra characters from below example.

```
$num = '4,063,500.00';
$filtered_num = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, 0, strpos($num, ".")));
echo $filtered_num;
o/p : 4063500
```

Comment: This will keep the number with the extra two zeros after the decimal `.`

Comment: @krishnaisdinesh Sorry, Regex is way too heavy, not a good solution for such a fairly simple problem

Comment: Thanks @PaulKaram for pointing. I've updated code as per requirement.